# using an if....else if statement over the entire page

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

```
ok so i have this if statement it is in the header.php

<?php 
    if (is_page('estate planning')) {
        $estate = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");} 
        elseif(is_page('probate & trust administration')){
        $trust = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");}
        elseif(is_page('elder law')){
        $elder = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");}
        elseif(is_page('meet sara')){
        $meet = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");}
        elseif(is_page('blog')){
        $blog = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");}
        elseif(is_page('client forms')){
        $form = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");}   
        elseif(is_page('request a consultation')){
        $request = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");}    
            else {
            $home = array ("homebg","hmline1","hmline","phone","home","blurb-hm");}
?>
```

how would i use this statement globally... like i want it to apply to the index.php header.php and footer.php.

i realize i can save it as bla.php and use include() on all the pages.
is there a more efficient way to do it like loading it globally from one page so the code looks neater and can be used on the the currently loaded pages?

Comment: If I may suggest, better is to use `switch ... case`. Make function returning not whether page is something, but returning a string what page is. The other way is to use `in_array()` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including the file with an `include('bla.php')` is the most efficient way of doing this. It's a single line of code to include the block and you're not repeating yourself.

Also re. Voitcus comment, you should be using switch instead of if to simplify this block. Get the page's name as a variable then do:

```
switch ($page) {
    case "estate planning":
        $estate = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");
        break;
    case "probate & trust administration":
        $elder = array ("eplnp","1","2","3","4","5");}
        break;
    ...
    default:
        $home = array ("homebg","hmline1","hmline","phone","home","blurb-hm");
}
```

Comment: i will try a switch statement it looks a little cleaner than if elseif.

i am trying include('header.php') right now to make it apply to the whole page. this worked but now i am picking up a capital S tagged onto the end of the array that i echo.

eg. echo $estate['0']

when i preview it in the browser it posts as: eplnS

i did a var_dump and looked at all the arrays there is no capital S in any of the arrays.
thoughts on were i would be picking up the capital S?

Answer (score 0):

> You can include file on header before wp_head(); and use any where
>   your variable.
>
> Add file on your selected theme folder.

```
require_once (TEMPLATEPATH . '/bla.php');
wp_head();
```